# How reactively add selected to an option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I'd like to write a jQuery function to reactivly add `selected` to a dropdown menu like this:

```
<select class="category">
       <option value=" ">  </option>
       <option value="car">car</option>
       <option value="pet">pet</option>
       <option value="game">game</option>   
 </select>
```

The funcation that I came up with is:

```
function updateSelectedCategory(catName) {
    $(".category option").each(function (k, v) {
        console.log(k, v);
        if (v.text() == catName) {
            v.prop("selected", true)
        }
    });
}
```

However despite several differnt attepts to get the option value and compare, I failed. So appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi, `v.text()` should be `$(this).text()` and here as well `v.prop("selected", true)` should be `$(this).prop("selected", true)` and `catName != cateName` please change them as well.

Comment: `!=` should be `==` only . In my comment i was just saying `catName` doesn't match `cateName`

Comment: @freedomn-m  That's not exactly the same question as mine, as I need an itteration over options to make comparision,  which turned out to be the main problem here.

Comment: @Swati right. I crrected the typos. Please answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @freedomn-m perhaps you are right and it can be done in one shot but I'm new to js and could not figure  out how to use that answer (which is not selected) to my particular use case.

Comment: `$(".category option:contains('"+catName+"')").attr("selected", true);`  but won't be an exact match, so depends on your use case.  In your sample data, this would be fine.

Comment: In your (typo-fixed edited) code, it should work if you change `v.text() != catName` *back* to `v.text() == catName` and use `$(v)` as advised in first comment.  https://jsfiddle.net/Lg58vy7u/